# Stop Sun Java System Web Server 7 reverse proxy resending long running requests

Tags: web-server, reverse-proxy, sun

We have a Sun Java System Web Server (7) running as a reverse proxy. When someone does a long running request (e.g. the web application does a major update on the DB) that doesn't return for a while (say 5 minutes) the proxy will *resend* the request to the back end web app, causing excessive load if it re-starts the operation.

Yes the web app can block re-requests, but the proxy should not resend the request, ever, period.

So the question is, how can I stop Sun Java System Web Server from re-sending requests?

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault, please take a look at [How to ask a good question](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask)